# Rounding off date/time intervals past midnight in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a Shift Management system which starts from 4.30 pm to 7.30 am, this goes past midnight, which means it returns two dates
How can I round off the time past midnight to previous date, in the current shift so that when we query a shift per date, it produces complete date

e.g. 2021-08-02 00:30:01 should read 2021-08-01 00:30:01

2021-08-02 03:30:01 should read 2021-08-01 03:30:01

2021-08-02 07:30:00 should read 2021-08-01 07:30:00

2021-08-01 11:30:01 should read 2021-08-01 11:30:01

Comment: How about adding example data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CASE WHEN TIME(datetime_column) BETWEEN '07:30' AND '16:30'
     THEN datetime_column
     ELSE datetime_column - INTERVAL 1 DAY
     END AS datetime_column
```